# why does it still call the form event handler when i click the cancel button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, form-submit

so i have this form that updates some user information, but when i click the cancel button it behaves like i clicked update which is the submit button,ive had this happen on another form but i figured out how to reset the input values so its the same as the default values. here is the code im using:

```
         const emailRef = useRef();
         const passwordRef = useRef();
         const confirmPasswordRef = useRef();    
     function handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirmPasswordRef.current.value !== passwordRef.current.value) {
              return setAlert("password do not match");
            }
            const promises = [];
            setLoading(true);
            setAlert("");
            if (emailRef.current.value !== currentUser.email) {
              promises.push(updateEmail(emailRef.current.value));
            }
            if (passwordRef.current.value) {
              promises.push(updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value));
            }
            if (usernameRef.current.value !== currentUser.displayName) {
              promises.push(updateUsername(usernameRef.current.value));
            }
            Promise.all(promises)
              .then(() => {
                setAlert("update complete");
              })
              .catch(() => {
                setAlert("failed to update profile");
              })
              .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
              });
          }

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="update-profile-form">
            <label className="label">Email</label>
            <div className="input-container">
              <input
                defaultValue={currentUser.email}
                ref={emailRef}
                type="text"
                required
              ></input>
            </div>
            <label className="label">Password</label>
            <div className="input-container">
              <input
                ref={passwordRef}
                type="text"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <label className="label">Confirm Password</label>
            <div className="input-container">
              <input
                ref={confirmPasswordRef}
                type="text"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="update-profile-buttons-div">
              <button
                className="cancel-button"
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
              <button
                disabled={loading}
                type="submit"
              >
                Update
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```